# Regex searching for a way to remove duplicate processing instructions from code

Tags: regex, search, replace, duplicates

I have an XML file that is littered with some processing instructions for page breaks.  Many times - these are duplicated.  Due to program constraints, we can't have duplicates.  The fix is to delete the duplicates.

Extract from XML

```
<cl:sect2 number="nonumber" identifier="c21_sect2-16">
<cl:complex-meta>
<cl:title identifier="NHBTUL192190904">title</cl:title>
</cl:complex-meta>
<cl:para identifier="YIGECN781336101">text in a para</cl:para>
<cl:para identifier="YIGECN781337102">text in a para</cl:para>
<cl:para identifier="YIGECN781337103">text in <?XSL PageEnd _567?> a para</cl:para>
<cl:para identifier="YIGECN781337101">text in a para</cl:para>
<?XSL PageEnd _568?>
<cl:para identifier="YIGECN781337102">text in a para</cl:para>
<cl:para identifier="YIGECN781337103">text in a para</cl:para>
<cl:figure number="numbered" position="fixed" identifier="FQOPWK022337863">
<cl:simple-meta>
<cl:title identifier="GIUSIS006030261">title text</cl:title>
</cl:simple-meta>
<cl:metadata-wrapper>
<cl:descriptive-media-meta>
<cl:media-term>Image</cl:media-term>
</cl:descriptive-media-meta>
</cl:metadata-wrapper>
<cl:media identifier="SUJESI135995607">
<cl:media-object media-size="page" height="550" width="206" units="pixel" link-target="95.jpg" identifier="UXNAAI395621596" asset-id="UXNAAI395621596"/>
</cl:media>
</cl:figure>
<?XSL PageEnd _568?>
<cl:para identifier="ECILBA810445866">text in a para</cl:para>
</cl:sect2>
```

In the above snippet, `<?XSL PageEnd _568?>` is the duplicate tag.

I had an idea that this could be remedied with a regex search-and-replace.

I started to think about the following...
Search: `(<\?XSL PageEnd _[[:alnum:]]+\?>)(?s:.*)\1`

Replace: `$1$2` 
<-- this doesn't work as I expected it to.

On a VERY small scale with less than 10 instances in the perfect scenario; I believe regex might be able to do the job

I run into issues:

1. Wrapped text doesn't work in my given example.
2. Catastrophic backtracking error when running a whole file (which
   could contain upwards of 1,000 of these).
3. If a PageEnd tag is duplicated MORE than twice. (176, 176, 176)
4. If a PageEnd tag is duplicated, but there's other pages that also might be duplicated between (176, 177, 177, 176, 176)

I think that regex was a good start - but it's just not remotely capable of completing this task in just Notepad++ alone.

If someone can help to point me in a direction that I can begin digging deeper into, I would greatly appreciate it. Although it may not be fully applicable, I have experience in VB and VBA as well as a little bit of PowerShell.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you show us the what the output looks like from your 4-line sample data?  By the way, I'm not sure that regex alone can/should handle this.

Comment: FYI the catastrophic backtracking comes from the fact that for each line matching `<\?XSL PageEnd _[[:alnum:]]+\?>` your current regex will match the rest of the file with `.*` then backtrack until it can match the latest duplicate of the initial line.

Comment: Without seeing what you are trying to do, it would be hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated the question to show a better example.

Comment: If there can occur several `<\?XSL PageEnd` you'd probably need a lookahead for overlapping. Assuming every line starts with `<` or contains space and between the `<?XSL PageEnd _` there is no other line starting with `<?` try like this and replace with `$2` without *dot match newline option*: [`<\?XSL PageEnd _(\d+)\?>\R((?><[^?].*\R|\s*)*?(?=<\?XSL PageEnd _\1\?>))`](https://regex101.com/r/D3OvAD/4)

Answer (score 0):

Check on the next regex `(?=(^<\?XSL PageEnd _\d+\?>$))(?<=\1[\s\S]+)\1`.

To try the regex online and get an explanation, please click [here](https://regex101.com/r/aSOI9R/3).

But this regex will only work with the engine, which supports an infinite repetition inside the lookbehind.